# How to replace color in an image without changing its texture/shades or brightness?

Tags: image-processing, color

I want to replace color in an image from another color: For that sample image is below

[image: sample image]

I want to replace color such that it becomes

[image: Resulted Image]

I know it can be easily done in Photoshop but I am looking for an algorithm which can replace a particular region color with another color but texture and shades should be preserved. These image are only for example.

I have tried changing hue and maintaining saturation and brightness but it fails when I try to change image to white/Black and nearby colors

```
<style>
  img{
      -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Can you post some images that show examples of how it fails?  That might give us some insight into what else to suggest.

Comment: You can post your first code to get more answer.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo : Thanks! I thought he needed rep to post ANY images. Didn't realize there's a limit of two.

Comment: you can look here: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=color%20lines%20image%20specific%20color%20representation